# C: sendto() to multiple clients - all messages going to same client?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am using UDP sockets to connect many clients to one server. After `recvfrom()`ing a client's login packet, I store their `struct addrinfo *` in an array like so:

```
struct addrinfo * userAddrs[64];

recvfrom(sockfd, req, 4096, 0, serverAddr->ai_addr, &serverAddr->ai_addrlen);
userAddrs[userindex] = (struct addrinfo *) malloc(sizeof(struct addrinfo));
memcpy(userAddrs[userindex], serverAddr, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
```

Then the the server receives messages from clients and sends it to everyone on that channel:

```
// user x channel matrix. 1 means listening on that channel.
int userchannel_matrix[64][64];
for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
    if(userchannel_matrix[i][channelindex] == 1){
       sendto(sockfd, &textsay, sizeof (struct text_say), 0, userAddrs[i]->ai_addr, userAddrs[i]->ai_addrlen);
    }
}
```

However, this ends up sending all of the messages to one client. Ex: If three clients are subscribed to channel 4 and one of them sends a message, that client will receive all 3 messages instead of each client receiving one. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the sockaddr family of structures? struct addrinfo is for use with getaddrinfo only.

Comment: I used addrinfo for my client to send messages to the server and it worked fine. My server can also send messages to the clients.

Comment: Well, there must be something going wrong with your userAddrs array and the data it contains. Have you tried printing out the ip/ports in presentation format and seeing what the go is? Also in the code sample you've provided, I don't see userindex being incremented. Is this being done 'outside' the sample?

Comment: Is there an easy way to print those out, or do I have to go grab each individual value for a `printf()`? Also yes, userindex is found based on the IP and port of the client, by looking at the `serverAddr` from the call to `recvfrom()`.

Comment: Use inet_ntop and ntohs like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105713/finding-the-source-ip-process-of-a-udp-packet/13105769#13105769 Altho this uses some C++ and is ipv4 specific, you get the idea.

Comment: I realized I already had a function to print those out. As you said, somehow they are the same IP and port, but that is to be expected I suppose. How can this happen though? If client with port 41889 sends a message, it says that userAddrs[0] = userAddrs[1] = 41889, but if a client with port 12345 sends it, then both values are 12345.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that struct addrinfo contains a *pointer* to a struct sockaddr, which you have clearly only initialized once. So every recvfrom() overwrites the same piece of sockaddr data (addrinfo.ai_addr), and every userAddr[] item points to the same one.

As @Troy suggested, you should be using struct sockaddr. Or else allocate all the addrinfo structures in the array *first,*, each with its own struct sockaddr *ai_addr pointers.

Comment: Found this out as soon as you posted it, I forgot that there were pointers even within the addrinfo struct... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others said, what you are implementing is basically a manual multicast, so why not just use an actual multicast instead?  That way, your server can `sendto() a single message to a single multicast IP group, and the OS will handle sending copies of the message to every client that has subscribed to that multicast IP group for you.